# Documentation about boost::unique_future

Tags: c++, boost

Run in the code into such construction **boost::unique_future**, but can't find much information about what is that. please, help providing links or explanation about that

Comment: A quick google search turned up [this in the docs for boost 1.54.0](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread/build.html#thread.build.configuration.future) So you'll have to look into the docs for earlier versions to find documentation for `unique_future`

Answer (score 1):

> unique_future is very much like unique_ptr: it represents exclusive
>   ownership of the value. Ownership of a (future) value can be moved
>   between unique_future instances, but no two unique_future instances
>   can refer to the same asynchronous value. Once the value is ready for
>   retrieval, it is moved out of the internal storage buffer: this allows
>   for use with move-only types such as std::ifstream.
>   [source](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/futures-and-tasks-in-c++0x.html)